# C++ System command outputs 0 at end

Tags: c++, command, system

So I am writing a C++ program that runs a command within the program. Whenever I do run the command though, it outputs a 0 at the end of whatever its supposed to output. Example:

```
The random int I was thinking of was 130
```

Where it is only supposed to output `The random int I was thinking of was 13` but it still outputs the 0 at the end. Here is my code to run the command:

```
printf("Running file: %s\n", fileName);
if(!exists(fileName))
{
    printf("That file does not exist.\n");
    return;
}
char buffer [7+strlen(fileName)];
int n;
n = sprintf(buffer, "php -f %s", fileName);
cout << system(buffer) << endl;
```

I dont think it has anything to do with the `php` command, because whenever I type into my terminal, `php -f <filenamehere>` it comes out with the `The random int I was thinking of was 13` output. I cannot think of anything else.

Comment: Don't `cout` the result of `system`?

Comment: `system()` returns 0 to indicate success (and non-zero to indicate failure). You print this 0.

Comment: @MatsPetersson How else would I output the output?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik How do I take out the 0 then :) ?

Comment: You don't send the return value of `system()` to `cout`, of course.

Comment: Another problem: wrong size of the buffer, there is no space for terminating 0, which means you are going out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `system` function returns the "result" of the execution, which is 0 for success, other values for various types of failure (including the result of the executable itself, if applicable).

You are printing that value using `cout`, which is why it's printing `0` - which is why it's printing `0`.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
int result = system(...);
if (result != 0) 
{
   cout << "system returned " << result << " which means it failed..." << endl;
}
```

Note that the output of whatever you run using `system` will go to `stdout`, it is not returned to the application itself, it is just printed to the console [or wherever `stdout` is going].

Answer (score 0):

system command return only the execution status.

To capture and print the output, see the options in this link

[How to execute a command and get output of command within C++ using POSIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c/)